# How do I detect NSDatePicker ValueChanged in MonoMac?

Tags: xamarin, monomac

Unlike UIDatePicker in Monotouch, the NSDatePicker in MonoMac does not appear to have "ValueChanged". How do I detect changes?

Ideally where datePicker is an NSDatePicker, I want to

```
datePicker.ValueChanged += DatePickerOnValueChanged
```

For events, I see "Activated" and "ValidateProposedValue", could it be the latter that I want?

**Update.** I think I can do something like below. Is it equivalent?

```
datePicker.Action = new MonoMac.ObjCRuntime.Selector ("datePickerAction:");
```

and

```
[Export("datePickerAction:")]
private void datePickerAction()
{
    // stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your ideal case, you say you want to use an event. The `ValidateProposedValue` event is fine for this:

```
picker.ValidateProposedDateValue += (object sender, NSDatePickerValidatorEventArgs e) => {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ProposedDateValue);
        };
```

It seems to correspond to the `NSDatePickerCellDelegate` method [datePickerCell:validateProposedDateValue:timeInterval:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/NSDatePickerCellDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html), which is what I would use in Objective C.